# Docker build creates and tags an image that docker run cannot find

Tags: docker

I have been given a project that is in a Docker container. I have managed to build the Docker container image and tag it, but when I run it I have problems.

```
bash-5.1$ docker build -t game:0.0.1 -t game:latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.584MB
Step 1/12 : FROM nvidia/cuda:10.2-base-ubuntu18.04
 ---> 84b82c2f5736
Step 2/12 : MAINTAINER me
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b8a86a8860d5
Step 3/12 : EXPOSE 5006
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fabdfc06768c
Step 4/12 : EXPOSE 8888
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a6f8585ce52d
Step 5/12 : ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c4dd4de87fdc
Step 6/12 : ENV WD=/home/game/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 871163f5db29
Step 7/12 : WORKDIR ${WD}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 36678a12e551
Step 8/12 : RUN apt-get -y update &&     apt-get -y upgrade &&     apt-get -y install git ssh pkg-config python3-pip python3-opencv
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4b83b4944484
Step 9/12 : COPY requirements.txt  /requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8e1db9206e80
Step 10/12 : RUN cd / &&      python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip &&     pip3 install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e096029d458a
Step 11/12 : CMD ["start.py"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 795bb5a65bc8
Step 12/12 : ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 59b472b693f2
Successfully built 59b472b693f2
Successfully tagged game:0.0.1
Successfully tagged game:latest
bash-5.1$ docker run -it -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix game:latest
Unable to find image 'game:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for game, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
bash-5.1$ sudo docker run -it -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix game:latest
```

It doesn't seem to find the game:latest image even though the output of the above command says it just created it.

I also try to do this after logging into my session.

I tried to run `59b472b693f2` (what is it, is it a container hash code?):

```
bash-5.1$ docker run 59b472b693f2
python3: can't open file 'start.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
bash-5.1$ ls
data_collection  demonstrateur.ipynb  demo.py  Dockerfile  examples  README.md  requirements.txt  serious_game  start.py  test
bash-5.1$
```

Here is the list of available images:

```
bash-5.1$ docker images 
REPOSITORY    TAG                     IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
game          0.0.1                   7e7ad7272cf0   15 minutes ago   1.77GB
game          latest                  7e7ad7272cf0   15 minutes ago   1.77GB
ubuntu        latest                  ba6acccedd29   7 weeks ago      72.8MB
hello-world   latest                  feb5d9fea6a5   2 months ago     13.3kB
nvidia/cuda   10.2-base-ubuntu18.04   84b82c2f5736   2 months ago     107MB
bash-5.1$ docker run -it -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix game:latest
python3: can't open file 'start.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
bash-5.1$
```

I tried to add it in the Dockerfile but still got the same error:

```
Removing intermediate container 10f2d7506d17
 ---> 1b776923e5a9
Step 11/13 : COPY start.py /start.py
 ---> 172c81ff16e9
Step 12/13 : CMD ["start.py"]
 ---> Running in c7217e2e0f21
Removing intermediate container c7217e2e0f21
 ---> eaf947ffa0b1
Step 13/13 : ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
 ---> Running in 77e2e7b90658
Removing intermediate container 77e2e7b90658
 ---> 924d8c473e36
Successfully built 924d8c473e36
Successfully tagged seriousgame:0.0.1
Successfully tagged seriousgame:latest
bash-5.1$ docker run -it -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix seriousgame:latest
python3: can't open file 'start.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
#############################################################################################################
#
#   Creation du container
#
##############################################################################################################

FROM nvidia/cuda:10.2-base-ubuntu18.04
MAINTAINER me

EXPOSE 5006
EXPOSE 8888

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV WD=/home/game/
WORKDIR ${WD}


# Add git and ssh
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y upgrade && \
    apt-get -y install git ssh pkg-config python3-pip python3-opencv

# Dépendances python
COPY requirements.txt  /requirements.txt
RUN cd / && \
     python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY start.py /start.py
CMD ["start.py"]
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
```

Here are all the files within my project:

```
bash-5.1$ ls
data_collection  demonstrateur.ipynb  demo.py  Dockerfile  examples  README.md  requirements.txt  serious_game  start.py  test
```

Comment: could you run `docker images` to check the list of available images?

Comment: can you try `docker run 59b472b693f2` to see if only the tag has issues

Comment: You have to run the same image you build using the same tag name. Now try executing it using `docker run -it -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix game:latest`.

Comment: Yes sorry, the output is updated @MarteValerioFalcone it can't find start.py

Comment: Ok, nice! Now Docker finally found your image after the build. In the step 11 of the build you run a python file called `start.py`, but you never copied it in the container before the step 11 of the build. You can add a line `COPY start.py /start.py` in your Dockerfile before the line `CMD ["start.py"]`. If you need to add all your code to your container, you should consider to go in the parent directory and `COPY parentDirectoryNameGoesHere /` instead of `COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt`

Comment: hmm that sounded wise @MarteValerioFalcone Unfortunately even after adding COPY start.py /start.py it still can't find it

Comment: maybe because start.py is not in the same dir of the dockerfile

Comment: Hmm I doubt so as it seems they are according to the output of the last command @MarteValerioFalcone

Answer (score 0):

In the first block of code you posted it says `Successfully tagged game:latest` and `Successfully tagged game:0.0.1`, but in your `docker images` output you don't see those images. Looking at the output of your `docker images` I see that the last time you built the image named `serious-game` was *1 hour ago*. I'm guessing so that you tried to rename the image, but the **image ID didn't change**.

You can try to **remove the old image** with `docker image rm` command ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_rm/)), and then try to **build it again**. The commands sequence to execute is the code block below. Data should be safe becouse I see that you're using volumes (I assume that you know what you're doing).

```
docker image rm 59b472b693f2
docker build -t game:0.0.1 -t game:latest .
```

The sequence `59b472b693f2` is the unique ID of the image in your Docker local environment (you can assume that it's an ID like the ones used in databases for indexing).

Comment: Many thanks Marte. I still consider myself as a noob with Docker. I know from the tutorials that volumes are used to make data peristent in Docker but that's all. Anyway, I can't remove the image because it is referenced in multiple directories

Comment: Here for help! As written in the command output and in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_rm/), you can force the command by applying `-f` flag. Command becomes so `docker image rm -f 59b472b693f2`.